# Testing to see if a jQuery UI Tooltip is open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to control the automatic opening and closing of a [jQuery Tooltip](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

How do I test to see if the current status of a tooltip is open?

I'm using the most recent versions of everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try by checking if there are any classes with `ui-tooltip`.

```
$(".ui-tooltip").length
```

Or, alternatively, you can use the API to check if it is open. You can set a flag and check using:

```
$(".selector").on("tooltipopen", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data("tooltip", true);
});
$(".selector").on("tooltipclose", function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data("tooltip", false);
});
```

To know the current status of the tooltip, you can use this:

```
$(".selector").data("tooltip");
```

It returns `true` if open, and `false` if closed. Hope this helps...

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. `$(".selector").data("tooltip");` (using my own selector of cause) returns undefined in console, while the bubble still remains. However, `document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip').length` returns 1

Comment: @ThomasWilliams This is an answer written 6 years ago. No wonder it might work or not now. Would you like to write a new question with a reference to this answer? Might help.