# JQuery tooltip auto-close time after click

Tags: jquery, user-interface, timeout, tooltip

I use the jQuery tooltip to call for prompting by clicking on the link and closing it after the mouseover.

**jQuery**

```
$('#realm').on({
    "click": function() {
        $(this).tooltip({ items: "#realm", content: "Copied", tooltipClass: 'tooltip'});
        $(this).tooltip("open");
     },
     "mouseout": function() {
         $(this).tooltip("close");
     }
});
```

But if the mouseover happens before the prompt is called, I get the error "Uncaught Error: cannot be reached before initialization; attempted to call method 'close'". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this answer : [ [Testing to see if a jQuery UI Tooltip is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970537/testing-to-see-if-a-jquery-ui-tooltip-is-open) ] 
You can check if the tooltip is open before trying to close

```
"mouseout": function() {
     if($(".ui-tooltip").length > 0)
        $(this).tooltip("close");
  }
```

A better option may be to set the flags as shown in the hyperlinked answer and use them to check if the given tooltip is open before attempting to close it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really what I need